# Integrity constraint violation error only on Server

Tags: php, mysql

I have `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:` error;

I think this is related with `foreign constraint`.

However my SQL looks correct.

Moreover it happens only on server not local.

1. localhost `mysql  Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`
2. server `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

My error message like this below.

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO AcStatus (friendsStr, followersStr, oneFriendsStr, oneFollowersStr, friendsNum, followersNum, oneFriendsNum, oneFollower  
  sNum, createdAt, updatedAt, enabled, ac_st) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2828207060,944898932982685696,1306248181,1028832299054325762,1030018  
  242280972288,1030020969190969344,1054737499443118082,1328082421,995233455683260417,1041877822199934976,1065186035569647616,985898196655259648,830752034085183488,9724266408  
  59934720,1082994874062786560,978215033778814977,915330694468984832,1018880555381751815,906489953814581249,1028032641310711808,1025004564422901761,1045576483840786432,10027  
  65007971602432,1089531262568562688,903352143146393600,1047803936457932801,224570452,138706740,995223326250254336,731377603676774400,970899520220311553,2292932660,317830558  
  9,38836238,803424126257885184,1009439059318431745,1056577591996440579", "830752034085183488,978215033778814977,1005728442657144832,1009439059318431745,44785665,10811191070  
  16085505,1056577591996440579", "2828207060,944898932982685696,1306248181,1028832299054325762,1030018242280972288,1030020969190969344,1054737499443118082,1328082421,9952334  
  55683260417,1041877822199934976,1065186035569647616,985898196655259648,972426640859934720,1082994874062786560,915330694468984832,1018880555381751815,906489953814581249,102  
  8032641310711808,1025004564422901761,1045576483840786432,1002765007971602432,1089531262568562688,903352143146393600,1047803936457932801,224570452,138706740,995223326250254  
  336,731377603676774400,970899520220311553,2292932660,3178305589,38836238,803424126257885184", "1005728442657144832,44785665,1081119107016085505", 37, 7, 33, 3, "2019-01-28  
   02:54:48", "2019-01-28 02:54:48", 1, 6]:                                                                                                                                    

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`twitmax`.`AcStatus`, CONSTRAINT `FK_F7258AEB7F7907  
  90` FOREIGN KEY (`ac_st`) REFERENCES `twitteraccount` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

These are my class.

```
class AcStatus
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\TwitterAccount", inversedBy="stIds")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ac_st",referencedColumnName = "id",onDelete="CASCADE")
    */

    private $acId;



    class TwitterAccount
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\AcStatus",mappedBy="acId")
     *
     */

    private $stIds;
```

Comment: Check the foreign key error section of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`, that'll give more detail about the violation. I expect that you are trying to insert a value that doesn't appear in the referenced parent table.

Answer (score 2):

`AcStatus` column has Foreign Key constraint `FK_F7258AEB7F7907` which causes violation.

You need to check Related Table values. It most probably does not have related data inserted on Foreign Table.

you can check error details by using `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`